# How to read multiple csv files into pandas and output in one csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, data-cleaning

I want to import in path structured csv files and output as a one CSV. My code just works with a path and a manually typed csv file.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

cols = ['Date', 'Time', 'Duration', 'IP', 'Request']
pd.DataFrame(columns=cols).to_csv('out9.csv', index=False, sep=';')

for df in pd.read_csv('query.csv', sep='\s',  header=None, chunksize=6):
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    df.fillna('', inplace=True)
    d = pd.DataFrame([df.loc[3,0], df.loc[3,1], ' '.join(df.loc[3,4:8]), ' '.join(df.loc[4,4:6]), ' '.join(df.loc[5,4:])])
    d.T.to_csv('out.csv', index=False, header=False, mode='a', sep=';')
```

I know there are some topics how to read many csv files, but in my case have not helped unfortunately.

I would like to read about it:

```
: C\Desktop\Files\*.csv
```

Information about the csv files:
All are built the same, that is, no header, same structures.
And I would like at a start of my code all in a folder read in and as a formatted again give out.

Therefore if possible to change the code as little as possible, I would only read several csv, instead of these a 'query.csv'

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `glob`:

```
import glob

cols = ['Date', 'Time', 'Duration', 'IP', 'Request']
pd.DataFrame(columns=cols).to_csv('out9.csv', index=False, sep=';')

for file in glob.glob('C:/Desktop/Files/*.csv'):
    for df in pd.read_csv(file, sep='\s',  header=None, chunksize=6):
        df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: `for file in glob.glob('Files/*.csv'):`instead ;)

Comment: for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/NZIP_Logfiles/*.csv'): is my path, but i get the error: line 14, in <module>
    d = pd.DataFrame([df.loc[3,0], df.loc[3,1], ' '.join(df.loc[3,4:8]), ' '.join(df.loc[4,4:6]), ' '.join(df.loc[5,4:])])
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected string, float found

Comment: This can be problem some data are converted to numeric, try add parameter `dtype` - `pd.read_csv(file, sep='\s',  header=None, chunksize=6, dtype=str)`

Comment: Output: ValueError: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex), but this causes 'dtype' to be ignored as it is not supported by the 'python' engine. (Note the 'converters' option provides similar functionality.)

Comment: it is only warning, no problem. add `engine='python'`

Comment: for df in pd.read_csv(file, sep='\s',  header=None, chunksize=6, dtype=str, engine='python'): with the error: ValueError: The 'dtype' option is not supported with the 'python' engine :(